# Input stream to pdf on Android

Tags: android, pdf, datainputstream, pdf-viewer

I am trying to save an input stream from a [HTTPSUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) to a PDF file stored on the device. It looks like it goes smoothly. However, when I loads the document in [PDFView](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview), I receive the following error: *PDF is corrupted*.

```
private void saveAsPDF(DataInputStream inputStream, final String filename)
{
    try {

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutputStream.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
        fileOutputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is how I load the pdf document in PDFView:

```
private void loadPDFData()
{
    File file = new File(princhDocument.getPath());

    pdfView.fromFile(file).onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void loadComplete(int i) {
            princhDocument.setNumberOfPages(pdfView.getPageCount());

            pdfView.recycle();
        }
    }).load();
}
```

Comment: can you post `IOUtils.toByteArray` ? What is `princhDocument.getPath()` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes. IOUtils.toByteArray is comming from apaches commons-io library which you can see here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream) and the path is a string of the path to the file.

Comment: @Blackbelt The path is received like this: context.getFilesDir().getPath()

Comment: you probably need the path to the file you saved. Try with `context. getFileStreamPath(filename.pdf).getPath()`